# Given that in $\Delta ABC$ we have $BC = 13$, $AC = 14$ and $C = \arccos(\frac{5}{13})$, find the elements of the triangle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Consider the triangle $\Delta ABC$ with $BC = 13$, $AC = 14$ and $C = \arccos(\frac{5}{13})$. I have to find the elements of the triangle. I am not sure of this, but by "elements of the triangle" I understand the lengths and angles of the triangle, so that's what I tried to find.

Using the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) like this:

$$AB^2 = AC^2 + BC^2 - 2 \cdot AC \cdot BC \cdot \cos(C)$$

I managed to find:

$$AB = 15$$

Using the fact that $\cos(C) = \dfrac{5}{13}$, the fact that $C \in (0, \pi)$ (so that means that $\sin C > 0$) and the identity $\sin^2 x + \cos ^ 2 x = 1$, I found:

$$\sin(C) = \dfrac{12}{13}$$

So now we have:

$$AB = 15 \hspace{2cm} AC = 14 \hspace{2cm} BC = 13$$

$$\sin(C) = \dfrac{12}{13} \hspace{2cm} \cos(C) = \dfrac{5}{13}$$

But I can't find the angles $A, B, C$. Through various methods I can find their sines and cosines, but I don't see any way of finding the measures of the angles themselves, and not the sines or cosines.

Comment: Everything you did was correct. I've posted a solution where I show how to find the missing angles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that $C$ is the biggest angle since it's opposite the largest side. And $C$ is acute since $\cos(C)>0$. Hence, all the angles are acute. So we can find the other angles using the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines).

For example, we have that

$$\frac{\sin(B)}{AC}=\frac{\sin(C)}{AB}.$$

Hence $B=\arcsin\left(\frac{56}{65}\right)$. $\;$ Etc.

Comment: I understand what you did, but isn't there a way to get exact answers without using a calculator? Like $C = 45 ^\circ $. Or all that is possible here is to get the angles in terms of arcsines and arccosines?

Comment: Saying that $B=\arcsin\left(\frac{56}{65}\right)$ is an exact answer. Once we know that $B=\arcsin\left(\frac{56}{65}\right)$, we can use a calculator to get an approximation, such as $B\approx59.489762^{\circ}$. Sometimes, our exact answer is something we can simplify. For example if $\theta=\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$, then $\theta=30^{\circ}$. But usually we're not able to get an exact answer that doesn't involve some inverse trig function such as $\arcsin$. For this problem, we have that $B=\arcsin\left(\frac{56}{65}\right)$, and as far as I know, we can't get a simpler exact answer.